How can I test linux driver without real hardware?
I'm new to embedded programming and currently developing an eSPI slave driver. Without physical hardware, I'm looking for a way to test this driver. Is there a method for testing in such a scenario? Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Use emulator, like QEMU.

@0andriy Thanks for your comment. Could you provide any link where I can learn more about this.
